# Is it possible to measure the length of an object using android phone's camera and a printed paper for scale?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I'm wondering if it is possible to make it so I take a picture with a printed scale( maybe a 2cmx2cm black square paper )and having this scale in the image as well as the object I am trying to measure. Is this possible with the android camera and cordova if so can anyone help thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It should be possible using some computer vision algorithms. Whether there are any that can do this "out of the box", and whether there are Cordova integrations for OpenCV or other computer vision libraries, I cannot say.

Comment: I haven't checked their help center, but I'd suggest asking on [android.se], since this doesn't seem - as currently written - to be a programming question.

Comment: anything is possible if you set your mind to it...

Comment: Thanks I was also wondering how i could count a specific color pixel in an image taken by the camera